# Push уведомления

Tags: java, android

В фоновом режиме приложение отправляет запросы на сервер, в цикле.
По задумке если ответ сервера содержит 1, надо отправить пуш уведомление.
Код работает но оповещение нельзя закрыть и при переходе по уведомлению оно не пропадает.И еще, когда сервер выводит 1 , оповещения приходят до тех пор пока 1 не сменится 0, как можно это исправить?

```
public class MyService1 extends Service {
public MyService1() {
}
private final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 38;
private NotificationManager nn;
String q = "http://site/new.php";
public  void  onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    new JSON().execute(q);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

public class JSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        while (true) {
            onCreate();
            try {

                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                return buffer.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result.contains("1")) {

            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            builder
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_name)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplication().getResources(),R.drawable.ic_action_name))
                    .setTicker("new messsege")
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle("Not")
                    .setContentText("put this mess");
            Notification notification = builder.build();

            notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

            startForeground(37,notification);
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: возможно, вам стоит полагаться не на "состояние", а на "события" сервера, кроме того, ваш цикл "while (true) " в doInBackGround() выполнится 1 раз в любом случае(из-за "return null" в его конце)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, то, что Вы называете "пуш уведомлением" называется [нотификацией](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) или уведомлением. [Push-сообщение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_push) -- это порция данных, которую Вам может прислать сервер. В вашем примере push-сообщения не используются.

Во-вторых, Вы не просто показываете нотификацию, а запускаете [foreground сервис](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?hl=ru#Foreground), в таком случае нотификацию нельзя просто смахнуть свайпом, ведь она связана с высоко приоритетной выполняющейся задачей. Если Вы действительно хотите запускать foreground сервис, то нотификация пропадёт только когда Ваше приложением вызовет [`stopForeground`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopForeground(int)) или когда пользователь убьёт его в настройках или по долгому тапу, если оболочка это позволяет (не через кнопку последних приложений).

В-третьих, если Вам нужно просто показать нотификацию, то необходимо воспользоваться `NotificationManager`, примеры [тут](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html) и [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/164-urok-99-service-uvedomlenija-notifications.html). С его же помощью нотификацию также можно удалить программно. Обратите внимание на установку `PendingIntent` в примерах, если необходимо что-то делать по нажатию на нотификацию.

Comment: Вместо startForeground(37,notification); я пробовал nn.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,notification); при запуске вылетело

Comment: Тогда обновите код и добавьте стектрейс.